# how to manipulate tensor array, 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I need to manipulate tensor as below

```
ary = np.array([82.20674918566776, 147.55325947521865, 25.804872964169384, 85.34690767735665, 1, 0]).reshape(1,1,1,1,6)

tf_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(ary, tf.float32)
value_x = 13.0
norm_value = 416.0

tf_array[...,0:4] = tf_array[...,0:4] * (value_x / norm_value)
```

when executed

TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign values in TensorFlow, as tensors are immutable (TensorFlow variables can have their value changed, but that is more like replacing their inner tensor with a new one). The closest thing to item assignment in TensorFlow may be [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update), which is still not assigning a new value, but creating a new tensor with some values replaced. In general, you have to find the way to *compute* the result that you want from the tensor that you have. In your case, you could do for example this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ary = np.array([82.20674918566776, 147.55325947521865,
                25.804872964169384, 85.34690767735665,
                1, 0]).reshape(1,1,1,1,6)
tf_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(ary, tf.float32)
value_x = 13.0
norm_value = 416.0

# Mask for the first four elements in the last dimension
m = tf.range(tf.shape(tf_array)[0]) < 4
# Pick the multiplication factor where the mask is true and 1 everywhere else
f = tf.where(m, value_x / norm_value, 1)
# Multiply the tensor
tf_array_multiplied = tf_array * f
# [[[[[2.568961   4.611039   0.80640227 2.667091   0.03125    0.        ]]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

I tried workaround

```
ary = np.array([82.20674918566776, 147.55325947521865, 25.804872964169384, 85.34690767735665, 1, 0]).reshape(1,1,1,1,6)

tf_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(ary, tf.float32)
value_x = 13.0
norm_value = 416.0

#create array of same shape and values to be multiplied with
temp = np.array([value_x /norm_value , value_x /norm_value, value_x /norm_value, value_x /norm_value, 1, 1]).reshape(1,1,1,1,6)

#convert numpy array to tensorflow tensor
normalise_ary = tf.convert_to_tensor(temp, tf.float32)

tf_array = tf_array * normalise_ary
```